# How to change button color while pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have some buttons on form.For example button1,button2,button3.I want to change button1 color while it's pressed,but as soon as i click button2,button1 color become default and button2 color changed.Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiqN2.png)

Comment: Post the code you have tried so fat. SO is not free code giving service.

Comment: Post code of your click handlers for all the listed buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Either using `MouseDown`event or using `FlatApparence.MouseOverDownColor`.

Comment: FlatApparence.MouseOverDownColor  for the win!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        button2.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        button3.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        button1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        button3.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
        button2.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        button1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button1,button2,button3 to your form and replece this code like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        button2.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        button3.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        button1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        button3.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
        button2.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        button1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;

    }
}
```

Comment: I posted the same answer buddy !

Comment: I tried to do like this before,but there too many code and it doesn't work like i want.

Answer (score 0):

Get The Container where it placed Buttons like Group Box ,Panel,Form,etc...

use Button Click Event to subscribe which button to change.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button1=sender as Button;
    if(button1 != null)
    setcolor(this,button1);
}
private static void setcolor(Control Container,Button btnFocus)
    {
        btnFocus.BackColor = Color.Red;
        foreach (Control Btn in Container.Controls)
        {
            if (Btn is Button)
            {

                if (btnFocus != Btn)
                {
                    Btn.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i hope this useful for u.